# Reload import in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, f2py

I'm trying to access some Fortran subroutines using `F2PY`, but I've ran into the following problem during consecutive calls from IPython. Take this minimal Fortran code (*hope that I didn't code anything stupid; my Fortran is a bit rusty..*):

```
! test.f90
module mod
  integer i
contains
  subroutine foo
    i = i+1
    print*,i
  end subroutine foo
end module mod
```

If I compile this using `F2PY` (`f2py3.5 -c -m test test.f90`), import it in Python and call it twice:

```
# run.py
import test
test.mod.foo()
test.mod.foo()
```

The resulting output is:

```
$ python run.py 
           1
           2
```

So on every call of `foo()`, `i` is incremented, which is supposed to happen. But between different calls of `run.py` (either from the command line or IPython interpreter), everything should be "reset", i.e. the printed counter should start from `1` for every call. This happens when calling `run.py` from the command line, but if I call the script multiple times from IPython, `i` keeps increasing:

```
In [1]: run run.py
           1
           2

In [2]: run run.py
           3
           4
```

I know that there are lots of posts showing how to reload imports (using `autoreload` in IPython, `importlib.reload()`, ...), but none of them seem to work for this example. Is there a way to force a clean reload/import?

Some side notes: (1) The Fortran code that I'm trying to access is quite large, old and messy, so I'd prefer not to change anything in there; (2) I could easily do `test.mod.i = something` in between calls, but the real Fortran code is too complex for such solutions; (3) I'd really prefer a solution which I can put in the Python code over e.g. settings (`autoreload`, ..) which I have to manually put in the IPython interpreter (forget it once and ...)

Comment: It looks like the script test.py imports itself. What does the Python code generated from test.f90 look like?

Comment: Sorry, poorly chosen name for `test.py`, I've renamed it (which gives the same result). Which generated Python code do you mean? `F2PY` is only giving me the shared object / dynamic library (or whatever it is called; the `.so` files) file, which I import in my Python script

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (I'm not very familiar with `F2PY`). What do you mean by "between different calls of `run.py`" — how is it being _called_?

Comment: Try explicitly initializing the value of `i` with `integer i = 0`. When a Python module is reloaded (with `reload(module)`) its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained. This means that unless there's module-level code that initializes their value(s), they will retain their current ones. Things may be similar with the dynamic libraries `F2PY` generates.

Comment: @martineau; calls from either the command line (`Python run.py`), or different `run run.py` calls from IPython. Re-initializing the variable would work, but as I wrote, that is unfortunately not an option with the real Fortran code that I'm dealing with; variables are implicitly declared/initialised inside the `subroutine` and kept with the `SAVE` statement, so that would be a nightmare.

Comment: You could try deleting the cached copy of the module the system keeps with a `del sys.modules['test']`.

Comment: Unfortunately that also doesn't work

Comment: IPython has something that does a "deep reload" named `dreload()`. See http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.9/html/interactive/reference.html

Comment: From what I see, that still only reloads the module if it has been changed. But anyhow, `dreload()` is giving me a `NotImplementedError`, which I don't understand. I'll look closer into it this evening.

Comment: Reloading only works for modules written in Python; you can't reloaded compiled modules (.so files).

Answer (score 1):

If you can slightly change your fortran code you may be able to reset without re-import (probably faster too).
The change is about introducing `i` as a common and resetting it from outside. Your changed fortran code will look this

```
      ! test.f90
      module mod
      common /set1/ i
      contains
      subroutine foo
      common /set1/ i
      i = i+1
      print*,i
      end subroutine foo
      end module mod
```

reset the variable `i` from python as below:

```
 import test
 test.mod.foo()
 test.mod.foo()
 test.set1.i = 0 #reset here
 test.mod.foo()
```

This should produce the result as follows:

```
  python run.py 
       1
       2
       1
```